# Delay when initializing Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am embedding Vue.js into an existing application.

When initializing Vue.js like so:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#myDomElement",
    data: myData,
    computed: {
        price: function() { 
            return _this.productPrice(); 
        },
    },
    created: function() { console.log("Vue created."); },
    beforeCompile: function() { console.log("Vue about to compile."); },
    compiled: function() { console.log("Vue compiled."); },
    ready: function() { console.log("Vue ready."); },
});
```

I am getting a lag of about 10 seconds at this point in my code. After this delay the lifecycle hooks (created, beforeCompile etc.) all fire at once.

The delay is independent of the view, even if `myDomElement` is an empty div the delay occurs.

Might be relevant:

- The `myData` object is not small but not huge either (28KB when JSON.stringified)
- The Vue.js initialization happens in a module, that is exported via `modules.export` and then wrapped up by Webpack

Comment: Please add the module code for further inspection.

Comment: @AaronFranco Thanks for having a look at it. I updated the question.

Comment: How do you know Vue is the bottleneck? With 2k lines of code, there could potentially be many possibilities for the bottleneck.

Comment: @AaronFranco The delay occurs if the `new Vue({...});` statement is there, the delay does not occur when this statement is removed, which indicates that Vue is at least involved in the delay.

Comment: Maybe you can work with this to reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/aaronfranco/yMv7y/1456/

Comment: Are you using JSDom to render the HTML?

Comment: Why are you using server side rendering with webpack?

Comment: @AaronFranco Thank you for your effort creating the jsfiddle, but I cannot post our whole app to it. I am pretty sure it is not Vue.js alone causing the behaviour. My hope is that someone with a similar setup like ours experienced something similar.

Comment: Vue is known to cause delays in server side rendering due to its two way bindings, which are not necessary if rendering server side. So, perhaps Vue is wrong for your project. The View Github has a feed specifically discussing server side rendering performance issues.

Comment: We aren´t rendering on the server. Thanks for the pointer, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out the data object `myData` was too complex (and it was significantly larger than stated by me in the original post).

The Vue.js documentation states

> It is not recommended to observe complex objects.

[see Vue.js docs](http://vuejs.org/api/#data)

We were able to move some data of the `myData` object to another object with no data binding and get the application running smoothly again.

Comment: This may have indirectly resolved an issue I was having in my own application. Upvoted for the documentation quote.